# Does the micro-service architecture for node reduce the efficiency and increase the response time？Is there any solution or my understanding is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

Recently, I use node to build a data processing system which involves many modules, so I plan to adopt a micro-service architecture and use a micro-service framework [Seneca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seneca) and use tcp to communicate.

the Seneca micro service are primarily responsible for communicating with database and data processing calculations(not time-consuming)

However, I found through ab test that the Seneca micro service is much less efficient than the original modules. In some cases, the average response time is 1.5 times than before. I think it is not hard to understand: Seneca micro service will generate additional communication overhead and some other overhead.

I am a little confused now. If I use micro-service architecture, I can solve the problem of mutual reference between modules in a large system. It is convenient for development. But it will reduce effciency and I feel that it is not worth the candle.

I don't know if my understanding of micro service is wrong, or there is something wrong the way I use it. I don't want to see that I use micro service but it reduces efficiency. So if you have some ideas, please tell me, thank you very much.

p.s. I temporarily think that there is no need to give sample code for this question, just want to hear your opinions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the success of a project is dictated not by the efficiency of how the application's components communicate but by how fast the application adapts to new business and technologic requests. This is easier to view in large applications, with a large code base and with possible many teams. Big monoliths are harder to change.

Microservices help by splitting a monolith in components that can evolve separately, with different technologies/frameworks and with different teams and at different speeds.

Microservices could also improve compute efficiency by using the right tool (programming language, framework) for the right job. For example JavaScript is good at asynchronous jobs while it sucks at 3D renderings or human face detection. Or when a new programming language is invented that would work best for some job, one could use it in a microservice without other microservices to know or to care.